# Finding problem with class copy construction

Tags: c++, class, constructor, copy

I have a problem with one of my c++ assignments. Its more of a theory question. Here is the code:

```
//a class implementation
class IntArrays {
public:
   IntArrays(int n): data(new int[n]), size(n) { }
   ~IntArrays() { delete[] data; };
   const int& operator[](int n) const
      { return data[n]; }

   IntArrays(const IntArrays& ar):
      data(new int[ar.size]),
      size(ar.size) {
      std::copy(data, data + size, ar.data);
   }

private:
   int* data;
   int size;
};

//a driver
int main()
{
    IntArrays a(100);
    IntArrays b = a;   // Problem!
      return 0;
}

In 1-2 sentences, explain why the second line of the driver program is problematic.
```

I really don't know what the error is with the second line of the driver because when I run it its fine. At first I thought it was because the = operator was not overloaded but the IntArrays b = a is using the copy constructor so thats not it. Im completely baffled, please help. This is going to bother me so much if I don't get an answer.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did this question come from a source you are certain is accurate and reliable?  Is it possible the person who posed it wrongly thought `IntArrays b = a;` would use `operator=`?

Comment: this is an assignment question, I copied it straight from the word file. I searched a bit before and it is using a copy constructor for IntArrays b = a; but it created from scratch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're copying the wrong way.

```
std::copy(data, data + size, ar.data);
```

Should be:

```
std::copy(ar.data, ar.data + size, data);
```

Comment: thanks, I don't know if thats what he meant by what is wrong with the second line since technically thats not in the second line but it is what the second line uses.

Comment: @Pete42: that accurately simulates real life, though - the line where you first observe a problem in your program is rarely the line containing the bug. Or maybe just because it makes the assignment too easy if the question is "what's the bug in the std::copy line"...

Comment: I agree with you completely, thanks you so much. We have never really created custom copy constructors in class so im new to it.